# How to clear dynamic memory?

Tags: memory, dynamic

For example, I have a dynamic segment tree on pointers, will the memory clear if I assign root of tree to NULL? How to clear it efiiciently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assigning to NULL will only change the pointer's address, but won't affect the allocated memory. The deallocation shall conform the allocation. This means if you have allocated each inode of the tree separately, you also need to deallocate them separately (most probably in the reverse order - depends on the content of the chunks). If all the memory was allocated at once, it should be also deallocated at once.

Comment: Is there a method to deallocate memory efficiently?

Comment: hmm, this is imho a very abstract question with no knowledge of the context. So I have only a general advice to avoid allocation of small chunks, but again this depends on your situation. Also hopefully reading about placement new might somehow help. The idea is to allocate a big chunk of the memory which will contain several/many small objects. Then the deallocating might be much efficient.